# Pareto Principle demonstration

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was simulating a popular pareto principle demonstration that goes as such:

1. get a bunch of paperclips
2. throw them into a pile
3. link two random chains/paperclips from the pile
4. throw the new chain back into the pile
5. repeat until 20% of chains have 80% of the paperclips

```
**no chain can be linked to itself.
```

This explanation didn't suffice so I decided to test how many distinct 'linkings' one has to do to achieve a 80/20 distribution. I tried to simulate it using java and I found that you need 0.75*paperclips random linkings to achieve a consistent 80/20 with any large (>100) quantity of paperclips.

Can anyone explain the math behind this? As in, how can we arrive at a result of ~0.75 through math and is it consistent with my code?